# How to backtest portfolio compositions using backtrader?

Tags: python, dataframe, finance, back-testing, backtrader

I have a csv file / pandas `dataframe` which looks like this. It contains various portfolio compositions for a portfolio which is re-balanced everyday according to my own calculations.

```
date        asset   percentage
4-Jan-21    AAPL    12.00%
4-Jan-21    TSM     1.00%
4-Jan-21    IBM     31.00%
4-Jan-21    KO      15.00%
4-Jan-21    AMD     41.00%
5-Jan-21    DELL    23.00%
5-Jan-21    TSM     12.20%  
5-Jan-21    IBM     15.24%  
5-Jan-21    KO      1.50%   
5-Jan-21    NKE     7.50%   
5-Jan-21    TSLA    9.50%   
5-Jan-21    CSCO    3.30%   
5-Jan-21    JPM     27.76%  
6-Jan-21    AMD     45% 
6-Jan-21    BA      0.50%   
6-Jan-21    ORCL    54.50%  
7-Jan-21    AAPL    50.00%  
7-Jan-21    KO      50.00%  
...
```

I want to test a strategy with a 12 asset portfolio.

`AAPL,TSM,IBM,KO,AMD,DELL,NKE,TSLA,CSCO,JPM,BA,ORCL`

So let's say on 4Jan2021, the portfolio's composition would be 12% in apple, 1% in TSM.. etc. I want to be able to check the prices and know how many I should be holding.

The next day, 5Jan2021, the composition will change to 23% in Dell.. etc, if the stock isn't in this list means its 0% for that day.

I have been looking at backtrader as a backtesting platform, however, the code I have seen in the repo mostly shows how to do stuff with indicators, like SMA cross over, RSI...

My question is: Is it possible to create and test a portfolio based on these compositions I have so I can check the return of this strategy? It would check this frame, and know how many stocks in a ticker to buy or sell on that particular day.

So the universe of stocks I am buying or sell is `AAPL,TSM,IBM,KO,AMD,DELL,NKE,TSLA,CSCO,JPM,BA,ORCL`

So on 4-Jan-21 it might look like,

```
dictionary['4Jan2021'] = {'AAPL':0.12,
                          'TSM':0.01,
                          'IBM':0.31,
                          'KO':0.15,
                          'AMD':0.41,}
```

On 5-Jan-21 it will look like,

```
dictionary['5Jan2021'] = {'DELL':0.23,
                          'TSM':0.122,
                          'IBM':0.1524,
                          'KO':0.015,
                          'NKE':0.075,
                          'TSLA':0.095,
                          'CSCO':0.033,
                          'JPM':0.2776,}
```

If the ticker isnt there means its 0%.
The portfolio composition needs to change everyday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you will want to do it load your targets with your datas. I like
personally to attach the target to the dataline as I add it to backtrader.

```
tickers = {"FB": 0.25, "MSFT": 0.4, "TSLA": 0.35}

for ticker, target in tickers.items():
    data = bt.feeds.YahooFinanceData(
        dataname=ticker,
        timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Days,
        fromdate=datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1),
        todate=datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31),
        reverse=False,
    )
    data.target = target
    cerebro.adddata(data, name=ticker)
```

In next you will want to go through each data, and determine the current allocation. If the current allocation is too far from the desired allocation (threshold) you trade all datas.

Notice there is a buffer variable. This will reduce the overall value of the account for calculating units to trade. This helps avoid margin.

You will use a dictionary to track this information.

```
def next(self):
    track_trades = dict()
    total_value = self.broker.get_value() * (1 - self.p.buffer)

    for d in self.datas:
        track_trades[d] = dict()
        value = self.broker.get_value(datas=[d])
        allocation = value / total_value
        units_to_trade = (d.target - allocation) * total_value / d.close[0]
        track_trades[d]["units"] = units_to_trade

        # Can check to make sure there is enough distance away from ideal to trade.
        track_trades[d]["threshold"] = abs(d.target - allocation) > self.p.threshold
```

Check all the thresholds to determine if trading. If any of datas need trading, then all need trading.

```
rebalance = False
for values in track_trades.values():
    if values['threshold']:
        rebalance = True

if not rebalance:
    return
```

Finally, execute your trades. Always sell first to generate cash in the account and avoid margins.

```
# Sell shares first
for d, value in track_trades.items():
    if value["units"] < 0:
        self.sell(d, size=value["units"])

# Buy shares second
for d, value in track_trades.items():
    if value["units"] > 0:
        self.buy(d, size=value["units"])
```

Here is the all of the code for your reference.

```
import datetime
import backtrader as bt

class Strategy(bt.Strategy):

    params = (
        ("buffer", 0.05),
        ("threshold", 0.025),
    )

    def log(self, txt, dt=None):
        """ Logging function fot this strategy"""
        dt = dt or self.data.datetime[0]
        if isinstance(dt, float):
            dt = bt.num2date(dt)
        print("%s, %s" % (dt.date(), txt))

    def print_signal(self):
        self.log(
            f"o {self.datas[0].open[0]:7.2f} "
            f"h {self.datas[0].high[0]:7.2f} "
            f"l {self.datas[0].low[0]:7.2f} "
            f"c {self.datas[0].close[0]:7.2f} "
            f"v {self.datas[0].volume[0]:7.0f} "
        )

    def notify_order(self, order):
        """ Triggered upon changes to orders. """
        # Suppress notification if it is just a submitted order.
        if order.status == order.Submitted:
            return

        # Print out the date, security name, order number and status.
        type = "Buy" if order.isbuy() else "Sell"
        self.log(
            f"{order.data._name:<6} Order: {order.ref:3d} "
            f"Type: {type:<5}\tStatus"
            f" {order.getstatusname():<8} \t"
            f"Size: {order.created.size:9.4f} Price: {order.created.price:9.4f} "
            f"Position: {self.getposition(order.data).size:5.2f}"
        )
        if order.status == order.Margin:
            return

        # Check if an order has been completed
        if order.status in [order.Completed]:
            self.log(
                f"{order.data._name:<6} {('BUY' if order.isbuy() else 'SELL'):<5} "
                # f"EXECUTED for: {dn} "
                f"Price: {order.executed.price:6.2f} "
                f"Cost: {order.executed.value:6.2f} "
                f"Comm: {order.executed.comm:4.2f} "
                f"Size: {order.created.size:9.4f} "
            )

    def notify_trade(self, trade):
        """Provides notification of closed trades."""
        if trade.isclosed:
            self.log(
                "{} Closed: PnL Gross {}, Net {},".format(
                    trade.data._name,
                    round(trade.pnl, 2),
                    round(trade.pnlcomm, 1),
                )
            )

    def next(self):
        track_trades = dict()
        total_value = self.broker.get_value() * (1 - self.p.buffer)

        for d in self.datas:
            track_trades[d] = dict()
            value = self.broker.get_value(datas=[d])
            allocation = value / total_value
            units_to_trade = (d.target - allocation) * total_value / d.close[0]
            track_trades[d]["units"] = units_to_trade

            # Can check to make sure there is enough distance away from ideal to trade.
            track_trades[d]["threshold"] = abs(d.target - allocation) > self.p.threshold

        rebalance = False
        for values in track_trades.values():
            if values['threshold']:
                rebalance = True

        if not rebalance:
            return

        # Sell shares first
        for d, value in track_trades.items():
            if value["units"] < 0:
                self.sell(d, size=value["units"])

        # Buy shares second
        for d, value in track_trades.items():
            if value["units"] > 0:
                self.buy(d, size=value["units"])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

    tickers = {"FB": 0.25, "MSFT": 0.4, "TSLA": 0.35}

    for ticker, target in tickers.items():
        data = bt.feeds.YahooFinanceData(
            dataname=ticker,
            timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Days,
            fromdate=datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1),
            todate=datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31),
            reverse=False,
        )
        data.target = target
        cerebro.adddata(data, name=ticker)

    cerebro.addstrategy(Strategy)

    # Execute
    cerebro.run()
```

####################################
#############  EDIT  ###############
####################################
There was an additional requiest for adding in variable allocations per day per security. The following code accomplishes that.

```
import datetime
import backtrader as bt


class Strategy(bt.Strategy):

    params = (
        ("buffer", 0.05),
        ("threshold", 0.025),
    )

    def log(self, txt, dt=None):
        """ Logging function fot this strategy"""
        dt = dt or self.data.datetime[0]
        if isinstance(dt, float):
            dt = bt.num2date(dt)
        print("%s, %s" % (dt.date(), txt))

    def print_signal(self):
        self.log(
            f"o {self.datas[0].open[0]:7.2f} "
            f"h {self.datas[0].high[0]:7.2f} "
            f"l {self.datas[0].low[0]:7.2f} "
            f"c {self.datas[0].close[0]:7.2f} "
            f"v {self.datas[0].volume[0]:7.0f} "
        )

    def notify_order(self, order):
        """ Triggered upon changes to orders. """
        # Suppress notification if it is just a submitted order.
        if order.status == order.Submitted:
            return

        # Print out the date, security name, order number and status.
        type = "Buy" if order.isbuy() else "Sell"
        self.log(
            f"{order.data._name:<6} Order: {order.ref:3d} "
            f"Type: {type:<5}\tStatus"
            f" {order.getstatusname():<8} \t"
            f"Size: {order.created.size:9.4f} Price: {order.created.price:9.4f} "
            f"Position: {self.getposition(order.data).size:5.2f}"
        )
        if order.status == order.Margin:
            return

        # Check if an order has been completed
        if order.status in [order.Completed]:
            self.log(
                f"{order.data._name:<6} {('BUY' if order.isbuy() else 'SELL'):<5} "
                # f"EXECUTED for: {dn} "
                f"Price: {order.executed.price:6.2f} "
                f"Cost: {order.executed.value:6.2f} "
                f"Comm: {order.executed.comm:4.2f} "
                f"Size: {order.created.size:9.4f} "
            )

    def notify_trade(self, trade):
        """Provides notification of closed trades."""
        if trade.isclosed:
            self.log(
                "{} Closed: PnL Gross {}, Net {},".format(
                    trade.data._name,
                    round(trade.pnl, 2),
                    round(trade.pnlcomm, 1),
                )
            )

    def __init__(self):
        for d in self.datas:
            d.target = {
                datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y").date(): allocation
                for date, allocation in d.target.items()
            }

    def next(self):
        date = self.data.datetime.date()
        track_trades = dict()
        total_value = self.broker.get_value() * (1 - self.p.buffer)

        for d in self.datas:
            if date not in d.target:
                if self.getposition(d):
                    self.close(d)
                continue
            target_allocation = d.target[date]
            track_trades[d] = dict()
            value = self.broker.get_value(datas=[d])
            current_allocation = value / total_value
            net_allocation = target_allocation - current_allocation
            units_to_trade = (
                (net_allocation) * total_value / d.close[0]
            )
            track_trades[d]["units"] = units_to_trade

            # Can check to make sure there is enough distance away from ideal to trade.
            track_trades[d]["threshold"] = abs(net_allocation) > self.p.threshold

        rebalance = False
        for values in track_trades.values():
            if values["threshold"]:
                rebalance = True

        if not rebalance:
            return

        # Sell shares first
        for d, value in track_trades.items():
            if value["units"] < 0:
                self.sell(d, size=value["units"])

        # Buy shares second
        for d, value in track_trades.items():
            if value["units"] > 0:
                self.buy(d, size=value["units"])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

    allocations = [
        ("AAPL", "4-Jan-21", 0.300),
        ("TSM", "4-Jan-21", 0.200),
        ("IBM", "4-Jan-21", 0.300),
        ("KO", "4-Jan-21", 0.2000),
        ("AMD", "4-Jan-21", 0.1000),
        ("DELL", "5-Jan-21", 0.200),
        ("TSM", "5-Jan-21", 0.20),
        ("IBM", "5-Jan-21", 0.1),
        ("KO", "5-Jan-21", 0.1),
        ("NKE", "5-Jan-21", 0.15),
        ("TSLA", "5-Jan-21", 0.10),
        ("CSCO", "5-Jan-21", 0.050),
        ("JPM", "5-Jan-21", 0.1),
        ("AMD", "6-Jan-21", 0.25),
        ("BA", "6-Jan-21", 0.25),
        ("ORCL", "6-Jan-21", 0.50),
        ("AAPL", "7-Jan-21", 0.5000),
        ("KO", "7-Jan-21", 0.5000),
    ]
    ticker_names = list(set([alls[0] for alls in allocations]))
    targets = {ticker: {} for ticker in ticker_names}
    for all in allocations:
        targets[all[0]].update({all[1]: all[2]})

    for ticker, target in targets.items():
        data = bt.feeds.YahooFinanceData(
            dataname=ticker,
            timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Days,
            fromdate=datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21),
            todate=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 8),
            reverse=False,
        )
        data.target = target
        cerebro.adddata(data, name=ticker)

    cerebro.addstrategy(Strategy)
    cerebro.broker.setcash(1000000)

    # Execute
    cerebro.run()
```

Comment: hi, thank you so much, this is great, now i have a starting point, i will read your code first and try it out, i have a question, if i already have lets say 10 apple shares today, and im going to buy 15 tomorrow, will it sell all 10 first then buy 15, or is there a way to just do 15-10 and buy 5 shares?

Comment: also, the % of the assets in each strategy will change everyday, sorry if that wasn't clear. so on 4th jan, appl: 12.00%, tsm 1%... but on 5th jan for strategy1, it might be appl: 50% and ko: 50%. can something like that be done?

Comment: The code above will provide an adjustment to the existing position to bring you in line with the desired target allocation. So if you have 10 xyz, and need 18, the system will by 8. Regarding your other question, you will just need to manage the target allocations coming in and make sure they are available into the algo each bar to establish the new allocations targets.

Comment: oh the rebalance part?

Comment: Sorry, Could you give me an example of where to fit the next day of target allocations please? I cant figure it out, because in this code, the data runs from 1 Jan 2019 to 31 Dec 2020. And I only see one allocation. So would I run the same code but with a for loop over multiple ticker dictionaries?

Comment: I think in your circumstance, I would try to load the csv file in the `init` of your strategy. Once loaded, I would create a dictionary with each `data` in your backtest as key, the strategy as second key, date as third key, and allocation as value.  Then in next, when ready to trade, you loop through your datas, and find the allocation as `[data][strategy][date] = target allocation`

Comment: im trying out your advice, but how do i select the date in the data object?

Comment: date is self.data.datetime.datetime()

Comment: So before data.target = target, I type data.datetime.datetime = datetime.datetime(2021,04,04) ?

Comment: i tried adding `if self.data.datetime.datetime() >= datetime.datetime(2021,2,11):` into `def next`, but I the code doesnt run

Comment: I"m honestly losing track of where your problem is.

Comment: I think I know how to clear it up, is it okay if I redefine the problem?, I think it’s not clear enough

Comment: Thanks for being so patient, im sorry if my question wasnt clear before, could you take a read again and see if it makes sense this time?

Comment: hey @run-out did you manage to take a look at my question again?

Comment: In my answer above, you load targets with each datas. You can load targets that have {date: allocation} dictionary for each data. All of your datas will now have allocations for each date. When you are inside 'next', you simply loop through each data, see if there is a target on that date, and then invest accordingly. Make sure you change the date from string to datetime inside 'next'.

Comment: if I loop through the date, how do I choose the asset name?

Comment: Each data will have {data: allocation} for each day. At each `next`, you loop through the datas. 
SORRY CANNOT FORMAT: 
date = self.data.datetime.datetime()
for data in self.datas:
    if data in self.target:
        allocation = data.target[date]
        ...do trading

Comment: is there a code example of this in the documentation? https://www.backtrader.com/docu/operating/ was the closest i could find in relation to the next function, i dont really get how it works, what about the current day?

Comment: Please see updated full code response. I trust this will now be satisfactory.

Comment: omg thanks man, this is perfect, im reading the code now trying to understand it, btw is there a way to save the output to a pandas dataframe? so i can compare the performance with out strategies?

Comment: That's another questions, but yes.

Comment: hi, do you know what  `f"o {self.datas[0].open[0]:7.2f} "` in the log means? Like what is index 0 in the datas ?

Comment: The first zero is which data in the list of datas you will use. datas is just a list. The second zero indicates this bar. You can use -1 for previous bar, -2 for two bars ago, etc. There is no plus 1 or 2. You can't look into the future.

Comment: This comment thread is too long, please ask other questions or move to backtrader community.